# Настройка Chrome DevTools

Tags: css, google-chrome

пользовался долго Firefox и теперь перешел на Chrome и сталкнулся с нехваткой такой маленькой мелочи.

Может кто то знает как в Chrome DevTools после подстройки стилей в css было отмечено маркером что бы визуально было видно что ты изменял ранее (до перезагрузки) 
Заранее большое спасибо тем кто хоть как то поможет с этой задачей)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]